# is it possible to build a spatial database using Dexie Db?

Tags: geospatial, geojson, indexeddb, dexie

I'm working on a web-based spatial data builder app designed to handle large datasets in real-time. Given the memory constraints of web applications, I need to efficiently manage the data being used. My goal is to load spatial data in 'chunks,' effectively loading only the data that is currently in view to optimize performance. To achieve this, I'm considering using Dexie to store the unused spatial data for quick retrieval.

Is it feasible to build a spatial database using Dexie for this purpose?